# Java dragging image and dropping on the point

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, drag, interactive

I want to create interactive drag and drop. What I mean is that i have 10 slots and 5 buttons, I want to make that user can drag and drop a button on the slot he wants to. I made it with ComboBox and it works fine but I want to make it more interactive. Is it possible in an easy way or I need a hard code? If so any good help on coding would be appreciated.

//Edit. I made it with ComboBox using setLocation(); with saved every slot position

//Edit again with photo:
[image: pic]

Comment: Please expand on your question to make it clearer in our minds including pertinent code, pictures, and more detailed explanations. Assume that we know nothing about your current project, your plans, and your code. In fact, if you write your question with the assumption in mind that we're ignorant dolts who have a hard time understanding you, you won't be that far from the mark and will likely write a very good question.

Comment: More interactive than ...? Post your code and a pic of your current interface.

Comment: Ok sorry. Edited. Posted a image for easier understanding. Sorry again.

Comment: BTW, drag and drop moves one component from one container to another. You are talking about slots. What is a slot?

Comment: Please give us more detailed explanations. Again, please post code, best, an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Again, assume that we're all ignorant dolts.

Comment: I don't have any code for this 'cause i didn't made it. I wanted a help for making a code for drag and drop. I can post object names or class name. This is all i have: Button, labels with image for this "slots" and a label panel that contains logo and labels. I Don't know where should I start and how can I do this. Again. I have no code for this. If you need any name or something tell me I will give you.

Comment: You may be premature at coming here with your question then. You should break down your problem into small steps, start simple with each small step and then move to putting it all together once the individual steps work. You will want to read a Drag & Drop tutorial as well. Also, why drag JButtons (which is what I assume your "buttons" are)? Why not JLabels that hold ImageIcons?

Comment: So it is possible to drag JLabels? How can i do this. And is it possible to read where dropped JLabel is and attach or put in the same position that "slot" is? Cause there I would be able to read Location of every JLabel and store it.

Comment: I mean. When i drag this round "button" with "options" name and drop it over "slot" number 3, i would like that this button will automatically get over this slot.

Comment: It's possible to drag any component, or even drag an image within a component.

Comment: Is the background and image or custom rendered component?

Comment: @azzurroverde Drag and drop describes any action where by any object is moved from one position to another using the mouse. You can change the position of elements, for example, JList and JTable do this, you can drag objects from outside the program in (or visa versa). So it's not limited to just moving compments between containers ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, kind of. In general yes. From the user point of view yes. In this case I was thinking about the Drag and Drop in  Java, DnD support offered by Java. I wanted to distinguish it by a mere move of a component. If he wants to just let the user move a component, like a Jlabel, from one position to another, he doesn't need to look at the java DnD, that offers more functionality. But still, it is not clear what he has in mind. How the "drop" should happen and if, besides position, the drop causes other actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can see several example of Drag and drop in Java here and decide which kind of drag and drop you would like to do:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/